# Lines look very "stretched"

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

Some lines of my document become very very "stretched". Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[bachelor, subf]{gost732}

\usepackage[a4paper,includefoot,
            left=3.5cm, right=1cm,
            top=2cm, bottom=2cm,
            headsep=1cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{pscyr}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage[perpage,symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\binoppenalty=10000
\relpenalty=10000

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}.} 
\renewcommand{\thechapterfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\prethechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\postthechapter}{.~}
\renewcommand{\appendixfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapterfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\sectionfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsectionfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theappendixalign}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\theappendix}{\arabic{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\pretheappendix}{\protect{Attachment}~} 
\renewcommand{\tocpretheappendix}{\protect{Attachment}~}
\renewcommand{\introname}{Introduction}
\renewcommand{\sectionindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\subsectionindent}{1cm}
\renewcommand{\aftersection}{6pt plus .1pt}
\renewcommand{\aftersubsection}{3pt plus .1pt}
\renewcommand{\conclusionname}{Conclusion}
\ifpdf\usepackage{epstopdf}\fi
\def\headfont{\small}
\pagestyle{headcenter}
\chapterpagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.\hfil}
\makeatother
\hyphenpenalty=10000
```

Here is an example. I have noticed that the line becomes  very "stretched" when there is a new indent after it. Why are they so "stretched"?

[image]

Comment: If you disable hyphenation but still ask for text to be justified on both left and right then stretching space is the only option. Perhaps you want `\raggedright` ?

Comment: Please, add the text of the offending paragraph. However, as I already explained, inhibiting hyphenation with a reduced line width and big font size is not a good idea.

Comment: You seem to enclose "The complement graph" into some box that disallows line breaks.

Comment: "The complement graph" probably starts a new paragraph, given the indentation difference between it and the following lines.

Comment: It seems like you are using `\linebreak` to end your paragraphs; if this is the case, remove those `\linebreaks` commands and leave a blank line, or use `\par` to end paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wouldn't use `\raggedright` though but rather `\RaggedRight` from the `ragged2e` package. Standard `\raggedright` looks extremely ugly. But then I don't know what difference there will be when you suppress hyphenation ...

Comment: Wow, there was \linebreak. It might be a copy-paste. Thanks, Gonzalo Medina, I couldn't find the reason. I replaced it with \par. Why is it impossible to increase your reputation in the comments?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Your comment is the answer. Please provide one ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel done!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like you are using `\linebreak` to end your paragraphs; if this is the case, remove those `\linebreak` commands and leave a blank line, or use `\par` to end paragraphs.